# numpy argmax when values are equal

Tags: python, numpy

I got a numpy matrix and I want to get the index of the maximum value in each row. E.g.

```
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[3,2,1]]
```

will return

```
[0,1,2]
```

However, when there're more than 1 maximum value in each row, `numpy.argmax` will only return the smallest index. E.g.

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

will return

```
[0,0,0]
```

Can I change the default (smallest index) to some other values? E.g. when there're equal maximum values, return `1` or `None`, so that the above result will be

```
[1,1,1]
or
[None, None, None]
```

If I can do this in TensorFlow that'll be better.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the expected output for `[[1,1,1],[1,2,2],[3,2,1]]` with some default value?

Comment: [`default`, `default`, 0] where `default` can be some preset value, better not be 0,1,and 2

Comment: WHat if the default is `2` for that case?

Comment: then [2,2,0] is acceptable, though [3,3,0] or [None, None, 0] might be better for future processing

Comment: What if the default is 0? My point is you can only have certain default values. So, if you feed in a wrong default one, how would you handle it?

Comment: Sorry I may not say it clearly, the ultimate purpose is to either 
1. when multiple maximum happens, set to some fixed value regardless of the index of maximum numbers
2. when multiple maximum happens, set to some special values so that I can handle this case later instead of silently use the smallest index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convenient value of "default" is -1, as `argmax` will not return that on its own. `None` does not fit in an integer array. A [*masked array*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) is also an option, but I didn't go that far. Here is a NumPy implementation

```
def my_argmax(a):
    rows = np.where(a == a.max(axis=1)[:, None])[0]
    rows_multiple_max = rows[:-1][rows[:-1] == rows[1:]]
    my_argmax = a.argmax(axis=1)
    my_argmax[rows_multiple_max] = -1
    return my_argmax
```

Example of use:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [4, 5, 3], [3, 4, 4], [6, 2, 1]])
my_argmax(a)   #  array([-1,  1, -1,  0])
```

Explanation: `where` selects the indexes of *all* maximal elements in each row. If a row has multiple maxima, the row number will appear more than once in `rows` array. Since this array is already sorted, such repetition is detected by comparing consecutive elements. This identifies the rows with multiple maxima, after which they are masked in the output of NumPy's `argmax` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.partition` two find the two largest values and check if they are equal, and then use that as a mask in `np.where` to set the default value:

```
In [228]: a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 2], [3, 1, 3, 2], [3, 5, 2, 1]])

In [229]: twomax = np.partition(a, -2)[:, -2:].T

In [230]: default = -1

In [231]: argmax = np.where(twomax[0] != twomax[1], np.argmax(a, -1), default)

In [232]: argmax
Out[232]: array([ 2, -1,  1])
```